# Rolling average in time series for specific time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data, I want to add a column that shows the moving average of the val column for each day.

```
df
timestamp            val    val_mean
2022-10-10 00:00     10       10
2022-10-10 00:01     20       15
..
2022-10-10 23:59     50       23
2022-10-11 00:00     80       80
```

How can I achieve this

Comment: moving average per day on which period?

Comment: for each day, update average every 1 minute. average resets when the time hits 00:00. I.e. Moving average in 1 minute intervals, for each day

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want a grouped, expanding mean:

```
group = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.normalize()

df['val_mean'] = df.groupby(group)['val'].expanding().mean().droplevel(0)
```

output:

```
          timestamp  val   val_mean
0  2022-10-10 00:00   10  10.000000
1  2022-10-10 00:01   20  15.000000
2  2022-10-10 23:59   50  26.666667
3  2022-10-11 00:00   80  80.000000
```